# how to create a local server for storing pdf file and displaying it in android app

Tags: android, server

I want to make an application which has a button and when it is clicked, i want to open another activity using intent and display the pdf file reading it from the local server in the phone.
But i am new to the server part of it. so it would be really helpful if someone could just eduacte me about that since am completely new to the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide us with enough details towards what you want to do.

Are your users uploading these PDFs and then viewing them within the app? Does the "server" implementation for your files have to handle different users for these files and provide authentication?

There are several different ways you can handle storing and accessing files in a "server". This is often referred to as the "back-end" component of your app.

If you need to handle user authentication and users uploading and accessing these files parse.com's android sdk is a really simple and easy way to prototype and get into this with a relatively easy learning curve. parse.com starts you off with a free plan and this can get you by for a long time. They start charging for api requests when you go over 30requests/sec or go over their 20GB of provided storage for their free account (see [here](http://parse.com/pricing))

Parse isn't the only provider of such services but I've used them before and find their SDK to be very simple and easy to use. The fact that you can use them for free (with limited resources) makes it great for prototyping or small apps. Firebase is an interesting one as well.

You could learn about servers and setup your own implementation for your users and files. You could purchase your own online storage solution or server. You could use libraries such as Square's OkHTTP ([Github link](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)) to speed things up. Doing a custom implementation would definitely be interesting and opens up the playing field so you can use many different languages and frameworks to get to your goal.

Comment: Thanks for that Roussy.

Comment: Actually I am new to android app development and i just wanted to do a small application for reading a pdf file from a local server and displaying it in my app. But i do not know to create a local server.And as of now i have no intention of making other users use this app but i want to the pdf file from the local server. Please help me if you could.

Comment: I am sure whatever you have written above will help me when i cross over the basic part of android.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: are you talking about displaying a **single** PDF file that would included with the app in local storage? Or do you really mean a PDF file that would stored on a server that you want the app to access and then display this PDF?

Comment: 'i want to the pdf file from the local server. '. A local server on your Android phone? What do you mean with local?

Comment: @Roussy i want to store that pdf file in a local server in the phone itself and then display that in one of the activity's in my application.

Comment: @greenapps i want a local server on my phone for storing the pdf file. am new to android and am just learning. i want that server only for my own usage and not for other users.

Comment: A server to STORE your pdf file on your phone? I would think a server to SERVE a pdf file on your phone. Please explain. If you want to use that server only on your phone then why you want a server? You could as well let your app load the pdf directly. So explain better what you want.

Comment: Ok what i want is just to learn about reading (Serve) a file from server and displaying it in my android app activity. So i though pdf file will be a good option. And as of now i want that server only for me to practice. So i though i would let it be on my phone itself.If there is any better way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: And i am not planning to launch the app as of now. So i don't need any complex servers.I just need the server to practice the basics like reading it and using in app  That's why am sticking with local servers on my phone.

Comment: `learn about reading (Serve) a file from server` ???? Please what do you mean as this is not understandable. You could make a client that reads a file from the server. But the server would serve the file. Not the client. So you have to make a server app and a client app. All is doable and a great exercise.